# What is the best way to shorten long variable accessors?

Tags: c++, class, function, variables

So I have a scenario where there are classes inside classes so that the access to a particular variable or function:

```
stateMachine->data->poseEstimate->getData()
stateMachine->data->poseEstimate->setData()
```

Now this is totally legitimate but it looks convoluted and is hard to read. In the function i want to be able to do something like this:

```
typedef stateMachine->data->poseEstimate pose

pose->getData()
pose->setData()
```

which will make the code more readable. Obviously `typedef` wont work because it is for defining types. Is there an equal way that will allow me to do this?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't make a reference variable that refers to said variable yet has a shorter name?

Comment: Not at all, i thought there would be a better replacement method though.

Comment: Is it possible that this situation came from lack of a clean interface? For example, could this be simplified with a helpers such as `StateMachine::GetPoseEstimate()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In practice, I alias said object with a reference variable given a descriptive name relevant to the context it's in:

```
PoseEstimateType& PoseEstimate = stateMachine->data->poseEstimate;
PoseEstimate->getData();
PoseEstimate->setData();
```

If your compiler supports the `auto` keyword, you can use an `auto` reference:

```
auto& PoseEstimate = stateMachine->data->poseEstimate;
PoseEstimate->getData();
PoseEstimate->setData();
```

Comment: is it possible in C to do something similar?  Using pointers directly gives error: `error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]`

Answer (score 2):

Store the intermediate object using a reference. We don't know your type names, but assume that `poseEstimate` is of type `MyType`:

```
MyType &pose = stateMachine->data->poseEstimate;

pose->getData();
pose->setData();

// ...
```

Comment: or better use `auto` if your version of C++ supports it

Comment: Suggesting a reference instead. Pointer grants more access than necessary. References give exactly what's desired, no more, no less. Unless there's an intent to reseat the reference, which is, of course, impossible.